# DNS resolution in Dockerfile FROM instruction

Tags: docker, dns, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile to build an image to be used internally in my company like this:

```
FROM internal-nexus/some/base-image
```

In my host machine (MacOS), I have the following entry in `/etc/hosts`

```
xx.yy.zz.vv internal-nexus
```

If I run `docker build` using above Dockerfile without pulling the base image in advanced, docker takes a long time to respond and finally times out:

```
request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

If I do a `docker pull` in host machine and then `docker build`, everything is working fine, docker can pull the base image and build using `Dockerfile`

I tried to specify `--add-host=internal-nexus:xx.yy.zz.vv` during `docker build` but it's not helping

My question is: how the `FROM` instruction resolves DNS and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you try to build with `--network host`?

Comment: @yamenk unfortunately it doesn't work either

Comment: What about `ARG myhost FROM ${myhost}/some/baseimage` and `docker build --build-arg myhost=xx.yy.zz.vv .`?